# Image behind button of app in scrollview

Tags: java, android

I want to create a scrollview but only in the upper part above my button. But my image shows below my button and I want it to stop above my button and I should scroll. I assign the image in my code, maybe this can be the issue.

Code of my xml file:

```xml
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_startdate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/show_enddate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:autoSizeTextType="uniform"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/show_image_war"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_show_war"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            android:text="@string/cancel_input"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code where I assign my image:

```java
File img_file = new File(imgPath);
ImageView imgView = findViewById(R.id.show_image_war);
imgView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(img_file));
```

Comment: You are using a RelativeLayout but the ScrollView and the Button have no attributes set where one references the other. So maybe you simply forgot to make the ScrollView end above the Button? (`android:layout_above="@+id/cancel_show_war"` )

Comment: Solved it. Thanks!